# Facebook JS picture field always undefined

Tags: javascript, facebook

I cannot figure out why the api call will not return the user's picture url. I know it has to be something super simple I'm missing.

The id and name return perfectly.

```
FB.api('/me', { fields: 'id, name, picture' },  function(response) {
alert("<img src="+response.picture+"/>"+response.name);
});
```

Output:

```
<img src=undefined/>John Smith
```

Comment: Taking it that you've logged response to see what it contains. Can you show us please.

Comment: Are you sure you can get it that way? Can't find this in the doc. Maybe you should use `/me/picture` instead https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/picture

Comment: picture is not a field it is an edge. So you need to request /me/picture

Comment: Wizkid can you provide an example of how to access that edge url then? and how it can be used to retrieve all friend pictures?

Comment: You can request it as a field, but it will return a data structure then, and not simply the URL – so log your response object to console to see what it actually contains. And no, you can not get all friend’s pictures, because you can not get all friends any more with API 2.0 – only the friends that are also users of your app will be visible to it.

Comment: To get picture URL use `picture.data.url`